# How to get a resource inside constructor?

Tags: java, file, resources

I have a file in the classpath and I am trying to get the file path using `class.getResource(String).getPath()` and it is returning NPE.

When I am doing the same from any method inside the same class, it is working fine.

Can't I access files using `getResource` method inside a constructor?

Comment: Yes, you can do getResource inside a constructor. If it returns null, that is because it is not finding your file. Make sure the path you give it is correct (it needs to be relative to the classpath root) and complete (not just the filename). Also `class` does not compile. You need to use either static `ClassName.class` or dynamic `getClass()`. Are you sure it is this line that causes the NPE, btw?

Comment: Show the code and the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

> Can't I access files using getResource method inside a constructor?
>   javafile

Yes you can.

The fact that you are calling `class.getResource()` inside constructor does not alter the method's behaviour.  If the target classes were the same and the resource paths were the same, then you should get the same result in either case.

I suspect that the difference in behaviour is down to something else.  For example, if you call `class.getResource` with the same path on different class objects, you may get different behaviour, either because the classes may have different classloaders, or because relative resource paths are resolved relative to the package name for the target class.

As @Dima points out, `getResource()` will return a `null` if it is unable to find the resource you have asked for.  That is the most likely cause of your NPEs (based on the sketchy info you have provided ...)

If this Answer doesn't offer you enough clues, then you need to provide us with SSCCE that illustrates the problem you are having.